# Fazer a requisição do CSS dentro do Body pode acelerar o carregamento da página e melhorar a performance da renderização?

Tags: html, css, desempenho, navegador-de-internet, http-request

**Primeiramente:**

Sabemos que algumas requisições feitas dentro do `<head>` do documento bloqueiam a renderização da página. E também sabemos que hj em dia é possível e permitido usar `links de folhas de estilo` dentro do `body`.

> If a `link element` has a `rel` attribute that contains only keywords that are **body-ok**, then the element is said to be allowed in the `body`. This means that the element can be used where phrasing content is expected.

Tradução: *"Se um `elemento de link` tiver um atributo `rel` que contenha somente palavras-chave que sejam **body-ok**, então o elemento é considerado permitido no corpo. Isso significa que o elemento pode ser usado onde o `phrasing content` é esperado."*

*Fonte:* https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#allowed-in-the-body

O que diz a Mozilla:

> Um elemento `<link>` pode ocorrer no elemento `<head>` ou `<body>`, dependendo se ele possui um tipo de link que é *body-ok*. Por exemplo, o tipo de `link` da `stylesheet` é *body-ok* e, portanto, a `<link rel = "stylesheet">` é permitida no `body`.

*Fonte:* https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link

---

***Pergunta:***

**Então posso considerar que o usuário vai ter uma percepção de que a página carregou mais rapidamente se eu estrutura meu documento assim?**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="header.css">
    <header>
        elementos etc...
    </header>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <main>
        elementos etc...
    </main>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="footer.css">
    <footer>
        elementos etc...
    </footer>

</body>

</html>
```

Dessa forma eu coloco primeiro o CSS crítico e posteriormente ele vem renderizando o resto do CSS que está abaixo da primeira dobra.

Posso considerar que o documento será renderizado em etapas então de cima para baixo? Tipo assim, o browser vai fazer a requizição do `<link rel="stylesheet" href="header.css">` ai renderiza, depois vai fazer a requisição do `<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">` ai renderiza, etc...

**Isso vai dar para o usuária a impressão, ou até de fato, vai carregar a página de forma mais rápida?**